# Como configurar Mapeamento Entity Framework 1:N usando herança

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Tenho duas classes: `Pessoa` e `Usuario`. A classe `Usuario` herda as propriedades e métodos da classe `Pessoa`.

Estou usando o Entity Framework e acredito está fazendo o mapeamento errado. Por isso está acontecendo o problema conforme a imagem abaixo.

A regra seria: Uma pessoa pode ser vários usuários registrados (parece estar errada a lógica, mas é por conta de uma necessidade minha) e um usuário só pode estar vinculado a uma pessoa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Mapeamento da classe Pessoa

```
public PessoaConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("tblPessoa");

    HasKey(p => p.PessoaId);

    Property(p => p.DataInclusao).IsRequired();
}
```

Código Mapeamento da Classe Usuario

```
public UsuarioConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("tblUsuario");

    HasKey(p => p.UsuarioId);

    HasRequired(p => p.Pessoa)
        .WithMany(u => u.Usuarios)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaId);

    Property(c => c.NomeUsuario).HasColumnName("NomeUsuario")
        .HasColumnType("Varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(25)
        .IsRequired();

    Property(c => c.Senha).HasColumnName("Senha")
        .HasColumnType("Varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(25)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

**Obs.:** A imagem está especificando a forma como a tabela deveria ficar no banco.

Comment: sim o entity framework joga o mesmo nome chave primaria da tabela que representa a classe base em todas as tabelas que representam as classes derivadas. Mas eu acho q isso esta dando erro na minha aplicação: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException.
No innerexcepition esta assim: A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY \"FK_dbo.Celula_dbo.Supervisor_supervisor_\". O conflito ocorreu no banco de dados \"repositorioEF.DB\", tabela \"dbo.Supervisor\", column 'Id'.\r\nA instrução foi finalizada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1:N de `Pessoa` com `Usuario` não tem como ser herança, infelizmente. Herança não supõe cardinalidade múltipla.

O caso de herança é algo assim:

```
public class Usuario
{ ... }

public class Pessoa : Usuario
{ ... }
```

Ou seja, uma `Pessoa` é um `Usuario`, mas um `Usuario` não precisa ser necessariamente uma `Pessoa`. Ambos ficam na mesma relação ou coleção no banco de dados.

No seu caso, o Entity Framework está certo em fazer as chaves em separado porque você está usando múltipla cardinalidade, e `Usuarios` e `Pessoas` não são a mesma coisa.

Se uma `Pessoa` tem vários usuários registrados, o correto é:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```